# Wpf canvas grid with coordinates

Tags: wpf, canvas

I have following canvas Code:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,40,40" 
                     ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,400,400"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="1"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

This canvas generates a grid like you can find it on excel.
Now I want to know if ist possible to generate the coordinates too. 
With cooridnates I mean that the first top row in the first fiels has a tiny text in it that says "A0" and the next one has "B0" and so every cell has coordinates like Excel.
Would this be possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but not with a TileBrush (because all tiles are equal). What did you try?

Comment: I have a grid with variable size and want it with an overlay, that looks like what this canvas does but with coordinates. Edit.: I dont know how I can do it without a TileBrush :/

Comment: You should get a WPF book and read a few chapters about the basics. There are a lot of controls like e.g. Path and TextBlock that allow to draw primitive or complex graphics and text. Without an own idea from your side we can't help much.

Comment: I know about the Basics but i dont know how I can dynamicly generate coordinates and set the in the exact place where every canvas rectangle is, so i thougt that it is maybe possible to edit this canvas part to do such a Thing.